# Python pygame event loop type error

Tags: python, events, loops, pygame, typeerror

I am making a simple pygame game. My problem is, when I try to check if the user is clicking the exit button, I get an error. Here's the Code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rafi\Python Programs\Game.py", line 20, in <module>
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Also, this probably doesn't but i'm on Windows 8.

Comment: What error do you get? From the tags, I would guess it's a `TypeError`.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, i'll edit in the error now.

Comment: You have to add all relevant code. What's going on around line 20, what's 'i'?

Comment: I am not familiar with pygame, but from the documentation, it looks like `QUIT` is a literal, not a method. If that's the case, doing `QUIT()` would cause this error. Here are some examples of other code using `QUIT`: http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.event.get.

Comment: sorry, somehow made a typo, meant event where it says i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is a constant (12 in case you were wondering).  It doesn't require any `()` after it.  That's all your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> pygame.QUIT
12
```

So,

```
>>> pygame.QUIT() >> 12()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

IN text, `pygame.QUIT = 12` so doing `pygame.QUIT()` is equivalent of doing `12()`, which is a call, which is not what you want.

Just change your line to:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```